# C# Process properties

Tags: c#, process, kernel

I'm using win platform and Unity3D game engine to create 3D app. When running, 3d application is in full screen mode. I'm using the following code to call VLC player from this app:

```
        string _path = "C:\\Users\\Saska\\Desktop\\Videi\\intro.mpg --fullscreen";
        foo = new Process();
        foo.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\Program Files\\VideoLAN\\VLC\\vlc.exe";
        foo.StartInfo.Arguments = _path;
        foo.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        foo.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized;
        foo.Start();
```

It happens that, when I run VLC, I see VLC window in the beggining (for 2 seconds, until it buffers a movie), then it gets minimized and I see the movie running in full screen mode. When it finishes, I have to close VLC manually, but it happens that my 3D application gets minimized and I have to click on it "to make it normal - fullscreen" again.
Is it possible:
- to avoid appearance of VLC window in the begging, just to see full screen movie play (I assume no, since VLC player reads the movie)
- to make my 3d app window running beneath VLC player in full screen mode so it happens that when VLC finishes I can see 3d app again in full screen mode
- to make VLC shuts down when the movie is finished
I'm new to process programming and don't know which terms to "google". I found process NET library, but I see no useful parameters.

Thank you very much.
Aleksandra

Comment: Doesn't Unity3D have APIs for video playback?

Answer (score 0):

You're better off using the [.Net Interface to VLC](http://wiki.videolan.org/.Net_Interface_to_VLC). It should be quite easy to use.

Here's a complete sample source code : [DMediaPlayer - Simple VLC frontend](http://dmediaplayer.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Thanks, but I have no time to integrate someone's library into Unity. Input argument "--intf dummy" is an option to start VLC without interface, and "vlc://quit" is to shut down VLC after movie -playlist is finished. Now I need to find an option how to play VLC on the top of my 3D app, without minimizing it. I think this matters the Process class from NET. Anyone?

Comment: Programming deserves patience. Unless you're just having fun with Unity3D, trying to work around the process properties will just end up complicating the whole issue for you. The VLC application may be overriding whatever process info you might have set. You can take a look at the ProcessStartInfo class to see other parameters, but you may end up needing to manipulate the process with an API function... and if you looked at the source code, you'd have finished it by now.